# Is there a way to display an error message to let the user know that the item selected is is being used in another table in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I get an error message every time I try to delete a value from my table that is being used in another table in the database. The error I get is there is a foreign key constraint which prevents me from doing so. Is there a way notify the user with a pop up message saying the item is being used in another table instead of the code breaking completely?

Here is my original code which just deletes from the table, it works it just doesn't delete if the value is in another table:

```
protected void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string EnvironmentID = DDlDelete.SelectedValue.ToString();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand co = new SqlCommand("exec spDeleteEnvironmentList '" + EnvironmentID + "'", con);
            co.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Sucessfully Deleted.');", true);
            Label1.Text = "Data has been Deleted";

            LoadRecord();
        }
```

Comment: Sure, but it's your job to display the error ;) Execute the code in a try/catch block and show an error if an exception is being thrown.

Comment: Why not have your code correctly delete only if it should do?

Comment: Agree with above. Use a query to test/check if the other record exists, and then take action. So, while you CAN trap the error? It nearly always better to avoid execution errors, and simple write the code to test for that other record, and then take correct action in code, and in fact when doing this, you can EVEN give the user a message about the other record that has to be dealt with. Such as : This product code is still in use by invoice number 3243xx. To delete this product you have to remove that invoice number 3243xx to delete this product. And  you can use a nice toast message or dialog